# Views - show only items not in a given nodequeue

Tags: views, nodes

Is there a way to filter on the value that is in nodequeue? I want to have a top 5 article list nodequeue, but I want a list of articles after that in terms of most recent is highest, except for those given nodequeue items. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Alright the answer is this:

You have to create a relationship with the nodequeue(s) in question that you wish to filter against. You have to make it so that the checkbox, "relationship required" is unchecked - otherwise it will primarily filter all items that are not in the nodequeue.

At this point, this will provide a filter to you termed, "in queue" - set this queue to false.

At this point, all items that are NOT in the nodequeue will be listed.